# Limit To BLE Devices?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

Is there a limit to the number of BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices that can transmit at the same time?

For example- if I plan to implement an IT solution that has to include several thousands of BLE Beacons / iBeacons- would it be a problem to monitor all these Beacons?

Would their transmissions interfere with each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BLE devices use multiple radio frequency channels for advertising and vary their specific packet transmission times in order to avoid transmission collisions with other BLE devices on the same channel.  I have successfully tested such a scenario with several dozen beacons visible at the same time, but there are limits to the built-in collision avoidance approach.

If you expect to have many hundreds of devices visible within the same ~50 meter transmission radius, you may run into trouble.  See  [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21991/how-many-active-bluetooth-devices-can-i-reliably-detect-in-a-single-space) for details.

Collisions of the transmissions will make it take longer for detection of each beacon.  CoreLocation on iOS and the Android Beacon Library provide a ranging update once per second for each device, but you may find  that each of these updates will include only a smaller percentage of the theoretically visible beacons because collisions prevented many of their packets from being received in a one second interval.  It all depends on your application whether or not less frequent updates are acceptable.

On Both iOS and Android there is no problem monitoring this large number of beacons as long as only a few dozen are in range at any given time.  On iOS, however, you need to make sure that you use only a maximum of 20 ProximityUUIDs across all the beacons, as this is the maximum number of Beacon Regions you can monitor at the same time on that platform.

Comment: Thanks @davidgyoung for your answer. This limitation pretty much puts a wrench in my solution. Is there any way to program Beacons to transmit only on command and stop transmitting on command?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible.  It is much easier to do so with mobile devices (iOS or Android) or laptops acting as beacons.  It is also possible with small dedicated hardware beacons, but this would typically require writing custom firmware.